# GUI framework design

Tags: user-interface, frameworks

I need to write a GUI framework, where I have no experience at all, not even using one. I'm a programmer for 25 years now, but not touched GUI in OO.

My questions:
 1. I'm using a special kind of programming language, where there is main event-loop that accepts all events and from there it has to dispatch the events. my question is, as a gui framework, to where I need to dispatch the event, for instance if a complex control like a List that has a scrollbar was scrolled, I get the event in my main event loop and I have to forward it to the complex control? or should it be routed to the scrollbar which is internal control in the List control, and then bubble it up to the List?
 2. Apart from sending the event to the control that triggered it, for the sake of taking the standart internal response - is there another responsibility that the framework should handle? I mean, does the framework should bubble the event also to the Dialog control that will be inherited later by the framework user in order to impliment the specific response to the events? or is it left to the framework user to dispatch the event to the dialog? I guess what I'm missing is what is the framework responsibility in terms of reacting to internal events.

Comment: This is a really broad and opinion-soliciting "discussion" - off-topic for StackOverflow.

Comment: what are the responsibilities of a gui framework, is a broad and opinion based issue? The questions is about trying to define what is a gui framework, in other words. What should it do exactly in order to be called a framework.

Comment: Yep - there's no definitive rule for what a gui framework should provide, or what something needs to provide to be considered a framework. It's a great discussion to have, but StackOverflow isn't the place for that (since it's not a discussion forum - it's a programming q&a site).

Comment: Yes I concur, far too broad and opinion based. That doesn't mean you can't have that discussion, just not here. IRC / reddit might be good choices.